# How to enable decorators for Mobx?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, mobx

I'm using Mobx (newbie) with a webpack config I built myself. When compiling I get

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (405:0)
```

At that line there is

```
> 405 | @inject('buttonStore')
```

So, decorators are not supported. How do I enable them? I'm using Babel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the official documentation:](https://mobx.js.org/best/decorators.html)

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-mobx
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["mobx"]
}
```

Also, remember that decorators are really just functions that don't require any transforms to work.

```
@observer
class ObservedComponent{}
```

...is equivalent to:

```
const ObservedComponent = observer(class ObservedComponent {})
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, I found the solution to the problem [here](https://georgik.rocks/how-to-build-app-with-mobx-annotations-via-webpack-using-babel-6/):

```
npm install babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy --save-dev
npm install babel-preset-stage-0 --save-dev
```

and put inside package.json

```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react", "es2015"
    ],
    "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy", "transform-class-properties"]
  }
```